# How to change method name dynamically in Razor with ASP.NET 3 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to change the method name dynamically for different pages.

My code is
(C#, ASP.NET, HTML)

```
if (IsPost)
{   
    if (Validation.IsValid())
    { 
    errorMsg = "";
    var input = Request.Form["awb"].Trim();
    errorMsg = @input;
    track trackObj = new track();

    **output = trackObj.tpc(input);**       

    <div class="row">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="result" sandbox="allow-same-origin" class="embed-responsive-item" src="@output"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
}
}
```

This is a code from one page of my website, I need to use same code in more than 20 pages. So I don't like to copy and paste the same code over every page.

I am looking for some concept to dynamically change the method name.

i.e

```
output =trackobj.tpc(input);
```

should be

```
output=trackobj.something(input); //in another page
```

In Razor, I have tried the following methods.

**1. Dynamic Instance**

```
@Page.MethodName="somename";
```

Is is leading to run-time error.

**2, Created new Render Area**

```
@RenderSection(somename,false);
```

It is displaying the method name in webpage.

**Is there any other possible way to change the method name dynamically for different website?**

or I have to copy that code manually for different page.?

Comment: When you say "change the method name dynamically" do you actually just mean conditionally call a different method? Otherwise I have absolutely no idea why you would want to do this.

Comment: Yes,conditionally. Based on the page, it should change the method name.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, its not possible, use a factory that resolves the target method call and you can use it. You can provide some hints to the factory on the caller etc. This will be a robust approach and pluggable.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Mustache](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache) framework to change the method name dynamically.